# Google Analytics Reporting, GoogleAnalyticsSDK, and a winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, google-analytics

In a simple windows forms application (1 form with 2 buttons) I am using the NuGet package GoogleAnalyticsSDK with the ["other platform" instructions](https://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Other%20platforms%3A%20Xamarin%2C%20WPF%2C%20Silverlight&referringTitle=Documentation).

The code appears to be working just fine, I can click a button and see the hot land on the google real time dashboard for that application. I cannot, however, find that hit again, later.

How do I use GA to "find" that hit. Maybe a custom report or something like that? All of the default reports are saying "There is no data for this view".

I am sending the following events via that SDK:

```
//send the main form
googleTracker.SendView("Main Form");

//send the button click
googleTracker.SendEvent("form_clicks", "button1_click", "Asked for submit", 0L);
```

In the GA real time view for screens and events, I see the "Main Form" view event hit, I also see the "button1_click" events that I send in. However I cannot find that view or event record later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you have to wait 24 hours or so to see your data show up in the other reports on GA. I am a noob, so it makes sense that I could not see that stuff.

Note that some reports can have their date ranges adjusted to include today, so if you give that a shot, you might see some of the data sooner - as it is processed on the GA side.